# MSELoss gives mismatching batch dimensions with batch size>1

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

Overview of the relevant code:

```
def train_net(net,
              device,
              epochs=5,
              batch_size=10,
              lr=0.1,
              val_percent=0.1,
              save_cp=True,
              img_scale=0.5,
              n_channels=5,
              n_classes=1):

    dataset = BasicDataset(dir_img, dir_gt, img_scale, n_channels)
    n_val = int(len(dataset) * val_percent)
    n_train = len(dataset) - n_val
    train, val = random_split(dataset, [n_train, n_val])
    train_loader = DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)

    writer = SummaryWriter(comment=f'LR_{lr}_BS_{batch_size}_SCALE_{img_scale}')    #Add folder location
    global_step = 0

    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        net.train()

        epoch_loss = 0
        with tqdm(total=n_train, desc=f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}', unit='img') as pbar:
            for batch in train_loader:
                imgs = batch['image']
                true_masks = batch['mask']
                assert imgs.shape[1] == net.n_channels, \
                    f'Network has been defined with {net.n_channels} input channels, ' \
                    f'but loaded images have {imgs.shape[1]} channels. Please check that ' \
                    'the images are loaded correctly.'

                imgs = imgs.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
                mask_type = torch.float32 if net.n_classes == 1 else torch.long
                true_masks = true_masks.to(device=device, dtype=mask_type)

                masks_pred = net(imgs)

                loss = criterion(masks_pred, true_masks)     
                
                epoch_loss += loss.item()
                writer.add_scalar('Loss/train', loss.item(), global_step)

                pbar.set_postfix(**{'loss (batch)': loss.item()})

                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(net.parameters(), 0.1)
                optimizer.step()

                pbar.update(imgs.shape[0])
                global_step += 1
```

When I choose a batch size of `1` the loss function doesn't give a warning. When I change it to `10`, it complains that:

```
:\workdir\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:446: UserWarning: Using a target size **(torch.Size([1, 1, 89, 99]))** that is different to 
the input size **(torch.Size([10, 1, 89, 99]))**. This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.

                                                                                                                                                                                      C:\workdir\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:446: UserWarning: Using a target size **(torch.Size([1, 1, 89, 99]))** that is different to 
the input size **(torch.Size([4, 1, 89, 99]))**. This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

However, when I debug, the shape of the input and target are both `[10,1,89,99]`. I think it's something about the training size and validation size...

```
Training size:   579
Validation size: 64
```

Does anybody know how to tackle this issue, so I can also work with larger batch sizes, larger than `1`?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the iteration over the batches (`for batch in loader: ...`) and the initialization of your dataloader (so we can see the batch_size and the other options) ?

Comment: *"the shape of the input and target are both `[10,1,89,99]`"*, are you sure this is true? The warning message seems to indicate your target tensor as a shape of `(1, 1, 89, 99)`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, if I debug with my breakpoint at the line after the loss, I see the tensor sizes are both [10,1,89,99]

Some extracts of my code below

Comment: The code should be put in the question, not in the comments. Anyway, you mentioned debugging with breakpoints. You said that line before the loss the tensor sizes are both OK. But did you look at that line at the first iteration, or at the iteration right before the failure ? Can you print their shapes at each iteration and run the program instead ?

Comment: Oh and the value of `batch_size` is still not visible in your code

Comment: The information presented is adequate to answer your question. You need to specify the shape of data and the size of output